# Differentiate $\dfrac{x}{y^2\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}~$with respect to $~x~$ where $~y = y(x)~$.

Tags: calculus

> Differentiate  $\dfrac{x}{y^2\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}~$with respect to $~x~$ where $~y = y(x)~$.

Having difficulty properly differentiating this function, I'm meant to show that the anti-derivative of
$$\frac{1}{{\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~\right)^3}}~.$$ is $$\dfrac{x}{y^2\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}~.$$

Comment: I am horrible at this code thing, first post on stack exchange

Comment: Differentiate with respect to what ? Write your questions clearly.

Comment: With respect to x, the edit made to the question changed the message of my second line I believe, though my code isnt great. Was meant to be that I'm meant to show the anti-derivative of $$\frac{1}{{\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~\right)^3}}~.$$ is the function I want to differentiate.

Comment: I hope that in managing to do so, I can show that it is indeed the antiderivative of that function.

Comment: __ I just put the format MathJax , nothing else. If the format is changed or any meaning is changed then you re-edit the whole.

Comment: By the way, what is $~y~?$ Is it $~y(x)~?$ or a constant ?

Comment: Did some edits to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Eventually figured it out, the question was unclear, the only way to properly show what I wanted was to assume that y was a constant, not y(x), which is strange given the context of this problem; but that becomes a question for physics, not math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing difficult in here. Just treat $y = y(x)$ as another function depending on $x$, hence when you differentiate it you get

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} y^2(x) = 2y(x)y'(x)$$

Where $y'(x)$ means the derivative with respect to $x$. Since $y(x)$ is an unknown function you just have to keep it as this.

The whole function can be written as $f(x)$ hence, applying the quotient rule for the derivatives, we get

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} f(x) = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{x}{y^2(x)\sqrt{y^2(x) + x^2}}\right)$$

Leading to

$$\frac{y^2(x)\sqrt{y^2(x) + x^2} - x\left[2y(x)y'(x)\sqrt{y^2(x) + x^2} + \frac{y^2(x)}{2\sqrt{y^2(x) + x^2}}\left(2y(x)y'(x) + 2x\right)\right]}{y^4(x)(y^2(x) + x^2)}$$

This can be simplified a bit:

$$\frac{1}{y^2(x)\sqrt{y^2(x) + x^2}} - \frac{2xy'(x)}{y^3(x)\sqrt{y^2(x)+x^2}} - \frac{x(2y(x)y'(x) + x)}{y^2(x)\left(y^2(x)+x^2\right)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Made a comment clarifying the antiderivative part, but this is still the correct answer for what the title is asking.